# Get pinax symposion running on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, pycharm, pinax

I'm want to do a small project with "Symposion".
A friend of mine was able to get it work on Mac, but I am constantly not able to get it work on my Windows 7 machine.

We are working with PyCharm, I tried to download it via this program, but he told me that there is no version satisfying my what ever.

I tried several ways of installing requirements via pip and everytime I get an error.

`"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement symposion."`

My Question: Is there anybody who can descripe me, how to get Symposion running on Windows?

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: In PyCharm he told me: "Could not find a version that stisfies the requirement symposion." As I uses pip to install the requirements of pixnas sample he pip says nearly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the zip file from here `https://github.com/pinax/symposion/archive/master.zip`
then `cd symposion` and run `python setup.py install`

Or as you have pip installed use:

`pip install https://github.com/pinax/symposion/archive/master.zip`

Using`pip install symposion` seems to give the error `"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement symposion"` but installing using `setup.py` or installing using pip with the url to the zip files works fine.